# Elasticsearch: Something is off with searching nested parameters

Tags: elasticsearch

```
PUT test
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "folks":{  
         "properties":{  
            "works_at": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


PUT /test/folks/1
{
  "type": "lawyer",
  "works_at": [
    { "location":"New York"},
    { "location":"Boston"}
  ]
}

PUT /test/folks/2
{
  "type": "lawyer",
  "works_at": [
       {"location":"Chicago"},
       {"location":"Boston"}
     ] 

}

PUT /test/folks/3
{
  "type": "writer",
  "works_at": [
       {"location":"San Francisco"},
       {"location":"Boston"}
     ] 
}
```

This search brings ZERO results:

```
GET /test/folks/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "works_at.location": "Boston"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "lawyer"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If the location portion is taken off the search:

```
GET /test/folks/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [

        {
          "match": {
            "type": "lawyer"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It will bring the right results:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "folks",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "type": "lawyer",
          "works_at": [
            {
              "location": "Chicago"
            },
            {
              "location": "Boston"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "folks",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "type": "lawyer",
          "works_at": [
            {
              "location": "New York"
            },
            {
              "location": "Boston"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I missing in my multi-search query?

Comment: hey @JsonGenX Could you please update the question with the mapping details?

Comment: @Kamal sure. added. thanks.

Comment: The query you've posted doesn't match to the fields in the mapping. In the query you have `works_at.location` while the mapping mentions only `location`. Did you check the mapping of the test using `GET test/_mapping` and verified if that is what you've mentioned in question above.

Comment: this is a copy/paste issue. I'm trying to simplify the problem...  I'll work on it more. In the mean time, do you know how to FORCE an "AND" and not an "OR"? What's the right syntax for that?

Comment: @Kamal I now have a full "non-working" example with all the necessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search a nested object you need to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

Since `location` is a property of `works_at` **nested object** you have to modify the query as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "works_at",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "works_at.location": "Boston"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "lawyer"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```